# Collapse json arrays into single array with combined key values

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I'm trying to combine multiple JSON arrays into a single array of collapsed like key values. Here's what I've gotten the code down to.

```
[
  {
    "projectId": 35525710,
    "jobs": [
        {
          "targetLanguage": "zh_CN",
          "jobId": 35826845,
          "earlyAccessStatus": "NOT_STARTED"
        },
        {
          "targetLanguage": "pt_BR",
          "jobId": 35826846,
          "earlyAccessStatus": "IN_PROGRESS"
        },
        {
          "targetLanguage": "zh_CN",
          "jobId": 35826836,
          "earlyAccessStatus": "IN_PROGRESS"
        },
        {
          "targetLanguage": "pt_BR",
          "jobId": 35826837,
          "earlyAccessStatus": "IN_PROGRESS"
        }
      ]
   }
]
```

The desired output would be: (***Edited below to take a different route***)

```
[
  {
    "projectId": 35525710,
    "jobs": [
        {
           "targetLanguage": "zh_CN",
           "jobIds": [35826845,35826836],
           "earlyAccessStatus": ["NOT_STARTED","IN_PROGRESS"]
        },
        {
           "targetLanguage": "pt_BR",
           "jobIds": [35826846,35826837],
           "earlyAccessStatus": ["IN_PROGRESS"]
        }
     ] 
   }
]
```

I'm not honestly sure what's going to happen with the duplicated `.earlyAccessStatus` key values, whether it will be `["IN_PROGRESS","IN_PROGRESS"]` or `["IN_PROGRESS"]`. The latter suits my eventual needs, which are to grab the `.targetLanguage` value for any language whose only `.earlyAccessStatus` is `["IN_PROGRESS"]`.

Using this filter with the `jq -r` option, I can pull out the `.targetLanguage` value for any languages whose only `.earlyAccessStatus` is `["IN_PROGRESS"]`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
.[].jobs[] | select(.[] | .earlyAccessStatus == ["IN_PROGRESS"] ) | .[] | .targetLanguage
```

Update:
Here is what the raw JSON looks like before I've manipulated anything. I'm not attached to any specific method. What I'm trying to do is take the data about a project with various jobs and isolate languages for whom all associated jobs have reached certain step (Target file export1) as indicated by "IN_PROGRESS". If the language has one job in a different step, like for instance zh_CN below, then that language isn't ready and shouldn't make it through the filter.

To get the output above, I had made it as far as (with one update made to eliminate the redundant arrays inside of "jobs" suggested already and I apologize in advance for whatever Frankenstein attempt at line separation you see in the jq command):

```
. | [{"projectId": .projectId, 
    "jobs": [( .jobs[] | 
        { "targetLanguage": .targetLanguage, 
          "jobId": .jobId,
          "earlyAccessStatus": (.steps[] | select(.workflowStepName == "Target file export1") | .status) } )] }]
```

Raw JSON:

```
{
  "projectId": 35902499,
  "completionStatus": "IN_PROGRESS",
  "activity": "ACTIVE",
  "sourceLanguage": "en_US",
  "jobs": [
    {
      "jobId": 35902526,
      "completionStatus": "IN_PROGRESS",
      "targetLanguage": "pt_BR",
      "steps": [
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Project Intake and Quote Generation1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Translate1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Correct1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Segment greenification1",
          "status": "FINISHED",
          "autoStatus": "SUCCESS"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Target file export1",
          "status": "IN_PROGRESS"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "jobId": 35902516,
      "completionStatus": "IN_PROGRESS",
      "targetLanguage": "zh_CN",
      "steps": [
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Project Intake and Quote Generation1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Translate1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Correct1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Segment greenification1",
          "status": "FINISHED",
          "autoStatus": "SUCCESS"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Target file export1",
          "status": "IN_PROGRESS"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "jobId": 36433561,
      "completionStatus": "IN_PROGRESS",
      "targetLanguage": "pt_BR",
      "steps": [
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Project Intake and Quote Generation1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Translate1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Correct1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Segment greenification1",
          "status": "FINISHED",
          "autoStatus": "SUCCESS"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Target file export1",
          "status": "IN_PROGRESS"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "jobId": 36433560,
      "completionStatus": "IN_PROGRESS",
      "targetLanguage": "zh_CN",
      "steps": [
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Project Intake and Quote Generation1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Translate1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Correct1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Segment greenification1",
          "status": "FINISHED",
          "autoStatus": "SUCCESS"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Target file export1",
          "status": "IN_PROGRESS"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "jobId": 36433552,
      "completionStatus": "IN_PROGRESS",
      "targetLanguage": "pt_BR",
      "steps": [
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Project Intake and Quote Generation1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Translate1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Correct1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Segment greenification1",
          "status": "FINISHED",
          "autoStatus": "SUCCESS"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Target file export1",
          "status": "IN_PROGRESS"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "jobId": 36433551,
      "completionStatus": "IN_PROGRESS",
      "targetLanguage": "zh_CN",
      "steps": [
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Project Intake and Quote Generation1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Translate1",
          "status": "FINISHED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Correct1",
          "status": "IN_PROGRESS"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Segment greenification1",
          "status": "NOT_STARTED"
        },
        {
          "workflowStepName": "Target file export1",
          "status": "NOT_STARTED"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

***New approach***

The saga continues. I have gotten so close by taking another route.

```
.[].jobs | 
    map({targetLanguage: .targetLanguage, 
        earlyAccess: {
            jobId: .jobId, 
            earlyAccessStatus: .earlyAccessStatus}}) 
        | group_by(.targetLanguage) 
        | map({targetLanguage: .[0].targetLanguage, 
            jobId: map(.jobId) | unique, 
            earlyAccessStatus: map(.earlyAccessStatus) | unique})
```

This gives me basically exactly the output I want, with the exception of the missing data that I need, which is, I suppose, a setback:

```
[
  {
    "targetLanguage": "pt_BR",
    "jobId": [
      null
    ],
    "earlyAccessStatus": [
      null
    ]
  },
  {
    "targetLanguage": "zh_CN",
    "jobId": [
      null
    ],
    "earlyAccessStatus": [
      null
    ]
  }
]
```

Ideally, this would instead output the unique values contained in the jobId and earlyAccessStatus keys like this:

```
[
  {
    "targetLanguage": "pt_BR",
    "jobId": [
      35826846, 35826837
    ],
    "earlyAccessStatus": [
      "IN_PROGRESS"
    ]
  },
  {
    "targetLanguage": "zh_CN",
    "jobId": [
      35826845, 35826836
    ],
    "earlyAccessStatus": [
      "IN_PROGRESS", "NOT_STARTED"
    ]
  }
]
```

That would let me easily filter for `targetLanguage` according to `earlyAccessStatus == ["IN_PROGRESS"]`.

Comment: aren't double arrays under `"jobs"` structurally superfluous? you already have grouping in objects, why do you need to keep each object in a separate array?

Answer (score 0):

All those 1-element long arrays are a pain, and I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but the following works:

```
jq '[.[]
     | .jobs |=
       [flatten
        | group_by(.targetLanguage)
        | .[]
        | [reduce .[] as $job ({jobId:[], earlyAccessStatus:[]};
             {targetLanguage: $job.targetLanguage,
              jobId: (.jobId + [$job.jobId]),
              earlyAccessStatus: (.earlyAccessStatus + [$job.earlyAccessStatus])})]
        | walk(if type == "object" and has("earlyAccessStatus")
               then .earlyAccessStatus |= unique
               else . end) ] ]' input.json
```

```
[
  {
    "projectId": 35525710,
    "jobs": [
      [
        {
          "targetLanguage": "pt_BR",
          "jobId": [
            35826846,
            35826837
          ],
          "earlyAccessStatus": [
            "IN_PROGRESS"
          ]
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "targetLanguage": "zh_CN",
          "jobId": [
            35826845,
            35826836
          ],
          "earlyAccessStatus": [
            "IN_PROGRESS",
            "NOT_STARTED"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rethink all those arrays-within-arrays, but the following achieves what you want except perhaps for the ordering of the groups, and of the keys:

```
# meld all the objects in the given stream of objects
def meld(objects): 
  reduce objects as $o ({}; 
    reduce ($o|keys[]) as $k (.; .[$k] += [$o[$k]]));


.[0].jobs |=
  (group_by(.[0].targetLanguage)
   | map( [meld(.[] | .[0] ) | .targetLanguage |= .[0] ] ))
```

This produces the output shown below. The simplest way to remove duplicates would be to add `unique`, e.g. as a final step in the `meld` function.

Similarly, if you want the groups ordered differently, you could specify the order as a post-processing step, or write your own `group_by`.

### Output

```
[
  {
    "projectId": 35525710,
    "jobs": [
      [
        {
          "earlyAccessStatus": [
            "IN_PROGRESS",
            "IN_PROGRESS"
          ],
          "jobId": [
            35826846,
            35826837
          ],
          "targetLanguage": "pt_BR"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "earlyAccessStatus": [
            "NOT_STARTED",
            "IN_PROGRESS"
          ],
          "jobId": [
            35826845,
            35826836
          ],
          "targetLanguage": "zh_CN"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured something out that worked! Went more the route of group_by and unique.

```
. | [{projectId: .projectId, 
      jobs: [( .jobs[] | { 
            targetLanguage: .targetLanguage, 
            jobId: .jobId, 
            earlyAccessStatus: (.steps[] | select(.workflowStepName == "Target file export1") | .status), 
            finalStatus: (.steps[] | select(.workflowStepName == "Target file export2") | .status) } )] }] | 
      .[].jobs | group_by(.targetLanguage) | map({
            targetLanguage: .[0].targetLanguage, 
            jobId: map(.jobId),
            earlyAccessStatus: map(.earlyAccessStatus) | unique, 
            finalStatus: map(.finalStatus) | unique})
```

This method works in two steps, first extracting the relevant data and organizing it like this:

```
[
  {
    "projectId": 35525710,
    "jobs": [
        {
          "targetLanguage": "zh_CN",
          "jobId": 35826845,
          "earlyAccessStatus": "NOT_STARTED"
        },
        {
          "targetLanguage": "pt_BR",
          "jobId": 35826846,
          "earlyAccessStatus": "IN_PROGRESS"
        },
        {
          "targetLanguage": "zh_CN",
          "jobId": 35826836,
          "earlyAccessStatus": "IN_PROGRESS"
        },
        {
          "targetLanguage": "pt_BR",
          "jobId": 35826837,
          "earlyAccessStatus": "IN_PROGRESS"
        }
      ]
   }
]
```

Once the content has been simplified in this manner, it is grouped by `.targetLanguage` and then the `.jobId`, `.earlyAccessStatus`, and `.finalStatus` keys are mapped for their unique values under each `.targetLanguage` key-value pair. I'm sure there is a simpler way to format this, but it accomplishes exactly what I set out to accomplish, leaving the data in this format:

```
[
  {
    "targetLanguage": "pt_BR",
    "jobId": [
      35902526,
      36433561,
      36433552
    ],
    "earlyAccessStatus": [
      "IN_PROGRESS"
    ],
    "finalStatus": [
      "IN_PROGRESS"
    ]
  },
  {
    "targetLanguage": "zh_CN",
    "jobId": [
      35902516,
      36433560,
      36433551
    ],
    "earlyAccessStatus": [
      "IN_PROGRESS",
      "NOT_STARTED"
    ],
    "finalStatus": [
      "IN_PROGRESS"
    ]
  }
]
```